# return a value from javascript in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am doing a small application with Vue.js, to return the distance between 2 cities, however I cannot get the returned value from my javascript function.  My code is pretty basic:-

```
<template>
<div>
  <label>Your distance is {{getDistance()}}</label>
</div>
```

```
  <script>
    export default {
    name: 'google-map-distance',
    data: function () {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDistance: function () {
      var distance = 0.00;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      var request = {
        origin      : 'London', // a city, full address, landmark etc
        destination : 'Manchester',
        travelMode  : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };

      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if ( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ) {
          distance = ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value) / 1000).toFixed(2); 
          console.log(distance);
          return(distance );
        }
        else {
          return( distance ); 
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I return the distance properly so that I can display it in my label?

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are calling an async process. So when you return the distance from within the callback, it wouldn't work.

Instead, you could use another variable to represent the distance, and set its value from callback. Something like this:

Template:

```
<template>
<div>
  <label>Your distance is {{distance}}</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    export default {
    name: 'google-map-distance',
    data: function () {
    return {
        distance: 0.00
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDistance: function () {
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      var request = {
        origin      : 'London', // a city, full address, landmark etc
        destination : 'Manchester',
        travelMode  : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };

      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if ( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ) {
          this.distance = ((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value) / 1000).toFixed(2); 
          console.log(this.distance);
        }
        else {
          // oops, there's no route between these two locations
          // every time this happens, a kitten dies
          // so please, ensure your address is formatted properly
          // this.distance = distance; // the distance in metres
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Note that I have merely replaced the distance variable in method `getDistance` with `this.distance` to refer to the observed variable. Also, I've changed the expression used in the template to show the `distance` variable.

This means that you will have to call the `getDistance` method through some other means - possibly a user click.

Comment: Hi Nisarg, thanks for the reply.  I tried that already but when I do it this way, the distance is always zero for some reason

Comment: @Johann I can't think of a reason for that. Can you create a working snippet/JS fiddle?

Comment: Sorry Nisarg, ignore my comment before, this works thanks a lot!

Comment: @Johann You're welcome!

Comment: just another question, lets say I return the 'this.distance' and I want to use it in another function as so :-      calcDistance: function () {
      var distance = this.getDistance();
      alert(distance);
    },    ---------distance now is undefined

Comment: @Johann The thing is you can't *return* any object/value from the callback function. Instead you could call the other function with `this.distance` as one of the parameters - from the callback. Something like: `this.calcDistance(this.distance)`.

Comment: I also tried           calcDistance: function () {
      this.getDistance();
      var distance = this.distance;
      alert(distance);
    },

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158299/discussion-between-johann-and-nisarg-shah).